# How can c# codebehind fire JavaScript code?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have some JavaScript code that will display a modal dialogue box asking the user to wait while it runs a web service that could take several seconds to run. What cannot figure out is how to launch the JS code from my C# code running in the server. Here is the scenario:

1) User clicks asp:Button code that launches server code. 
2) Server code [somehow] fires a browser event that launches the JS code that calls the web service

The JS code looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btn_BeginProcessB').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $Seconds = $("INPUT[id*='txtSeconds']").val();
                var $Message = $("INPUT[id*='txtMessage']").val();
                var $WorkingMessage = $('#WorkingMessage');
                $WorkingMessage.text($Message);

                var $this = $(this);
                var $Loader = $('#Loader');
                // show loading indicator              
                $Loader.show();
                $("body").css({ background: "#C8C5C5" });
                // Begin process
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ Seconds: $Seconds }),
                    url: 'SimpleWebService.asmx/LongRunningProcess',
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error! ' + errorThrown);
                        // show button
                        // hide loading indicator                
                        $Loader.hide();
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Data:" + data.d);
                        // show button
                        // hide loading indicator                
                        $Loader.hide();
                        $("body").css({ background: "#FFFFFF" });
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LoadPageWorking() {
            var $Seconds = $("INPUT[id*='txtSeconds']").val();
            var $Message = $("INPUT[id*='txtMessage']").val();
            var $WorkingMessage = $('#WorkingMessage');
            $WorkingMessage.text($Message);
            var $data = JSON.stringify({ Seconds: $Seconds });
            PageWorking('Loader', 'SimpleWebService.asmx/LongRunningProcess', $data, PageWorkingSuccess, PageWorkingError);  
        };

        function PageWorkingSuccess(data) {
            $("SPAN[id*='lblResult']").html("<br /><b>Result:</b>" + data.d + "<br />");
            $('body').css('background', originalBackground);
        };

        function PageWorkingError(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error! ' + errorThrown);
            $('body').css('background', originalBackground);
        }
    </script>
    <!--- HTML --->
    <div id="Page">
        <h1>
            Long Running Process Test Page</h1>
        <p>
            This site demonstrates how to invoke a long running process and let the user know
            that the process is underway. When the button is clicked, it calls a web service
            that sleeps for the designated number of seconds and returns a message.</p>
        <br />
        Enter number of seconds for worker process to sleep:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSeconds" runat="server" Width="25" Text="3" /><br />
        Enter the message to be displayed while the process is working:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Text="Working...(please be patient)"
            Width="300px" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnBegin" value="Click to test LoadPageWorking function"
            onclick="LoadPageWorking();" />
    </div>
    <div id="Loader">
        <center>
        <span id="WorkingMessage">Default Loader Message</span>
            <div class="ProgressBar-Animated">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

What code can I write in my C# event that will fire the LoadPageWorking() JS function?

Comment: Why not have the click event of the button fire the LoadPageWorking function.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you have a server side button control, you can use it's `onclientclick` property to call javascript directly. But if you have to call the script from code behind, you can use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)  or [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)  based on your requirement. There are plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 3):

Have the button trigger a page working function that creates some indicator that you are working, fire off the ajax request, and when it comes back finish the working and hide the indicator. No need to ever have to go to code behind.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have your `LoadPageWorking()` start the server, then show the JS modal popup? You can have your popup poll your service to determine if it's completed, and hide itself when it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) method. It will allow you to dynamically add script sections to your page's source. You can include any Javascript you'd like, including invocation of a method already defined in the page.